# Making bread dough in the bread maker and baking it in the oven

Tags: oven, bread

I am in the process of making bread in the bread maker, but I want to try to bake it in the oven. I am just making white bread. What temp and how long would you recommend baking the bread?

Comment: How big of a loaf (in cups of flour)?

Comment: 2 lb. I'll break it into two 9x6 pans

Comment: Sorry. 4 cups of flour

Comment: Do you by any chance have a stand mixer?  It'll do most of the same work as your bread machine and you can use a standard recipe.

Comment: Yes I do. I ordered "Artisan Bread in Five Minutes a Day: The Discovery That Revolutionizes Home Baking" so I can experiment more.

Comment: @Mike - the Artisan Bread book should get you a long way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a 2lb loaf (or 2 x 1lb loaves) I'd recommend about 22-25 minutes at 350F.

Comment: I did 350F for 40 minutes and it came out good.

Answer (score 5):

General answer: for bread in a bread pan, 350°F until 195°–205°F in the center. That'll probably be around 40 minutes, I'd guess (and it seems you found) but a thermometer will let you be sure (and then you'll know how long it takes for next time).

Answer (score 3):

15 minutes at 230C, then another 15-20 at 200C, until it's risen and sounds hollow when you tap the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Allrecipes says:     * Most bread is baked in a moderate oven, 350 degrees F (175 degrees C). Bake for 40 to 50 minutes, or until the crust is golden brown and the bottom of a loaf sounds hollow when tapped.

Me? I just go to Cub Foods ..

Comment: Except that I can't have malt and almost all boughten bread has malted barley.

Answer (score 2):

Baking time depends on a lot of factors:

- loaf size
- oven temperature
- baking with or without tin
- dough type (wheat/rye/mix/...)

Safest choice would be to use an oven thermometer.

The loaf is done at 97 or 98°C core temperature.

Another indicator is the sound of your loaf: if you knock on its bottom and it sounds hollow, it's done.

Also important: experience. Bake the same recipe until you're used to it and the result satisfies you. If the result isn't perfect: don't worry. You'll end up with something edible in every case and don't need to starve.

For a nice crust, start with 250°C and turn the oven down to about 220°C when you put the bread in.

For an even nicer crust, you'll need steam. Not only humid air but STEAM. This question covers this topic: [How can I create steam in a normal oven to promote bread oven spring?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/21627)

For the best result you can achieve at home with a simple oven use a pizza stone. Heat it up to 250°C for 1 hour. Then put in the loaf and produce some steam.

Answer (score 1):

Your bread machine recipe might be different from a regular bread recipe.

When baking, I usually preheat my oven to 250C with a deep pan at the bottom rack with a few cups of water. This is important to keep the dough moist but give a good crust. When it comes time to bake, I pop mu loaf in and drop the temp to 200C. I usually stop when I achieve a golden colour. But you can go darker if you want.

Comment: I'll try the water next time, that sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Put hot water in a square baking pan on the bottom oven rack. 
Bake bread at 350 degrees for 25 minutes for a light crust. 
The hot water is crucial for keeping the bread moist.