# How can I keep the crust of my breads from getting too dark?

Tags: baking, bread

Some of the breads that I bake the crust gets too dark.  Is there something I can put over it to prevent this from happening? I was thinking that foil might work but I'm not sure. Will this affect the taste? And if it's ok to use, do you put it on tightly or loosely?

Comment: This question about the opposite issue might have some information that's useful to you about browning: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/75443/how-to-reduce-cracking-and-increase-browning-in-sourdough-loaves/75943#75943

Answer (score 5):

Foil will reflect heat, and I have a canonical answer on here someplace about using it to modify baking in ovens that have issues with, say, burning the bottom of a loaf.

But if the whole loaf is affected, the problem is one of temperature or ingredients (or the intersection of the two.) Less sugar in the dough will reduce browning of the crust, and lower temperature will also reduce browning of the crust. Assuming you are happy with the overall taste, I'd start with turning the oven down, not attempting to shield the whole loaf with foil. You may need to increase baking time at lower temperature.