# Re bread: What is the best way to introduce steam into home ovens?

Tags: oven

What is the best way to introduce steam when baking bread? I’ve tried water-soaked volcanic stone (used in grills), and a simple pan of pre-heated water.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create steam in a normal oven to promote bread oven spring?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21627/how-can-i-create-steam-in-a-normal-oven-to-promote-bread-oven-spring)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried them all.  Honestly, my best results are achieved baking in a cast iron pot with a cover.  While I can only bake one shape, the convenience of not having to mess with stones, ice cubes, or steam burns, and the fantastic results make it worthwhile.

Comment: My experience is similar, though I have  pans with no official cover, so I use aluminum foil or in one case I beat a heavier aluminum take-out container into a good-enough fit for one of my pans. I've yet to see the point in spending actual money on a new "cloche"  pan with cover, and this does work much better than the various water-adding tricks I've tried in the past. I just yank the cover 15-20 minutes from the end of baking for browning.

Comment: @Ecnerwal, certainly a good idea...some people find placing the dough on a pizza stone, and covering with a large stainless bowl easier than dealing with a preheated cast iron pot.  So, that is also an option.